# Unable to unit test scopes inside a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-scope, karma-runner

I am trying to write unit tests for my code for the first time. I can test $scopes when declared at the top of my controllers, but how can i test $scopes that are inside a $scope function?

Ctrl:

```
app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, $http, myService) {
    $scope.initialiseValue = 0;

    $scope.address = function (value) {

        $scope.addressValue = 0;

    }
});
```

Test:

```
describe('app', function () {

    var app;
    beforeEach(function () {
        app = angular.mock.module('app')
    });

    describe('MyCtrl', function () {
        var scope, ctrl, theService , httpMock;

        beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, myService, $httpBackend) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new(),
            ctrl = $controller('MyCtrl', {
                $scope: scope,
                $location : location,
                myService: theService ,
                $httpBackend: httpMock
            });
        }));

    // This test succeeds ///////////

    it('initialiseValue should be initialised to 0', function() {
        console.log(scope.initialiseValue );
        expect(scope.initialiseValue ).toBe(0);
    });

    // This test fails ///////////
    it('addressValue should be initialised to 0', function() {
        console.log(scope.addressValue );
        expect(scope.addressValue ).toBe(0);
    });

});
```

Error:

```
Expected undefined to be false.
```

Using Karma and Jasmine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to call the

```
scope.address()
```

function inside the test. If you do not call this function,

```
$scope.addressValue
```

can not be updated. Updated working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/themyth92/j3pkaebw/1/